# spring cloud stream kafka binder, how to set different max.polls.records settings for two consumers?

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

application.yml

```
    bindings:
  first-consumer-in-0:
    destination: consumer.first
    use-native-encoding: true
    group: ${spring.application.name}
    content-type: application/*+avro
    consumer:
      batch-mode: true
      concurrency: 1
      partitioned: true
      max.poll.records: 500
      configuration.isolation.level: read_committed
  second-consumer-in-0:
    destination: consumer.second
    use-native-encoding: true
    group: ${spring.application.name}
    content-type: application/*+avro
    consumer:
      batch-mode: true
      concurrency: 1
      partitioned: true
      max.poll.records: 10
      configuration.isolation.level: read_committed
```

I set different max.poll.records values for first and for second consumers. But when my spring boot application started, I have seen what settings for both consumers the same: 500, like as first.

```
14:45:10.225 [main] [some-service,,] INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values: 
allow.auto.create.topics = true
auto.commit.interval.ms = 100
auto.offset.reset = earliest
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:29092]
check.crcs = true
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.rack = 
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
enable.auto.commit = false
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = some-service
group.instance.id = null
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = []
internal.leave.group.on.close = true
internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
isolation.level = read_uncommitted
key.deserializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 500
```

My question: how i can specify different values of max.poll.records for different consumers ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the **max.poll.records** configuration incorrectly. If you want to specify consumer settings in this way, you must give them at the **binder level.**

You can also set the **time(fetch.max.wait.ms)** and **size limit(fetch.min.bytes)** as I shared in the sample code.

And if you are consuming in batch, you need to give deserializer as well.

Here is an additional point you should pay attention to. If any of the 3 values specified there are provided, you will consume the data. In other words, when it takes 10 seconds or 10000 bytes or 100 records, data is consumed.

Other than that, it will definitely work when you do it this way. All my microservices are working with these settings. Try it, you'll see it works.

I am sharing a sample code.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
      binders:
        bulkKafka:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9092
                      configuration:
                        max.poll.records: 100
                        fetch.min.bytes: 1000000
                        fetch.max.wait.ms: 10000
                        value.deserializer: tr.cloud.stream.examples.PersonDeserializer
        anotherBulkKafka:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9093
                      configuration:
                        max.poll.records: 500
                        fetch.min.bytes: 1000000
                        fetch.max.wait.ms: 10000
                        value.deserializer: tr.cloud.stream.examples.PersonDeserializer
      bindings:
        first-consumer-in-0:
          binder: bulkKafka
          destination: consumer.first
          use-native-encoding: true
          group: ${spring.application.name}
          content-type: application/*+avro
          consumer:
            batch-mode: true
        second-consumer-in-0:
          binder: anotherBulkKafka
          destination: consumer.second
          group: ${spring.application.name}
          content-type: application/*+avro
          consumer:
            batch-mode: true
```